# Pytorch reinforcement learning explanation

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am attempting reinforcement learning to create a chess engine. I found some code online in Python with Pytorch. I am more familiar with tensorflow so can somebody help explain what the code means and maybe help "translate" it into tensorflow code?

Also, is the currently defined model "robust" enough to be decent? If not, how can I improve it? I have tried adding more nn.Linear lines to it but it seems to weaken the model.

EDIT: Here is the original link to the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Xk9MibJ9Fli5tIlDvo88hcZrI76rqZN5#scrollTo=ZxHEghUq9JWM

EDIT2: Also, I want to figure out how to implement a system to use its memory of previous results into the current code. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Note that the code below was ADAPTED from the link.
Adapted Code:

```
import chess
import chess.pgn
import chess.engine
import torch
import numpy as np
import os
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
#os.remove("Games.txt")
def board_to_tensor(board):  
    # Python chess uses flattened representation of the board
    x = torch.zeros(64, dtype=torch.float)
    for pos in range(64):
        piece = board.piece_type_at(pos)
        if piece:
            color = int(bool(board.occupied_co[chess.BLACK] & chess.BB_SQUARES[pos]))
            col = int(pos % 8)
            row = int(pos / 8)
            x[row * 8 + col] = -piece if color else piece
    x = x.reshape(8, 8)        
    return x


def move_to_index_tensor(move):
    index_tensor = torch.LongTensor([0])
    square_to_pick_figure = move.from_square
    # Can decode exact position this way:
    #square_to_pick_figure_row = int(square_to_pick_figure / 8)
    #square_to_pick_figure_col = int(squre_to_pick_figure % 8)
    square_to_put_figure = move.to_square
    # Can decode exact position this way:
    #square_to_put_figure_row = int(square_to_put_figure / 8)
    #square_to_put_figure_col = int(square_to_put_figure % 8)
    index = square_to_pick_figure * 64 + square_to_put_figure
    index_tensor = torch.LongTensor([index])
    return index_tensor
  
def filter_legal_moves(legal_moves):
    filtered_legal_moves = []
    for legal_move in legal_moves:
        # Here we check if it is a promotion and
        # only leave promotion if it is a promotion to a queen
        if legal_move.promotion is not None:
            if legal_move.promotion == 5:
                filtered_legal_moves.append(legal_move)
            continue
        filtered_legal_moves.append(legal_move)
    return filtered_legal_moves


def legal_moves_to_index_tensors(legal_moves):
    legal_moves_index_tensors = [move_to_index_tensor(legal_move) for legal_move in legal_moves]
    return legal_moves_index_tensors

# The input to the network is a tensor of size 8*8 (it is flattened)
# The output of the network is 64*64 (it is flattened too)
# The size of the hidden layer should be 512

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, number_of_actions=64*64):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        
        # Fill up the values below in nn.Linear()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(64, 512)
        self.layer5 = nn.Linear(512, number_of_actions)
        
        # Initialization of weights in the layers
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.layer1.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.layer5.weight)
        
                
    def forward(self, x):
        x =  F.relu( self.layer1(x) ) 
        # Logits will be fed into softmax layer to get probabilities
        # for each move later.
        logits =  self.layer5(x)
        
        return logits

net = Network(number_of_actions=64*64)

def discount_rewards(collected_moves, gamma=0.99):
    running_reward = 0.0
    for index, collected_move in enumerate(reversed(collected_moves)):
        reward = collected_move[1]
        running_reward = running_reward * gamma + reward
        collected_move[1] = running_reward
  

def normalize_rewards(collected_moves):
    normalized_rewards = np.asarray(list(map(lambda x: x[1], collected_moves)), dtype=np.float)
    normalized_rewards -= np.mean(normalized_rewards)
    normalized_rewards /= np.std(normalized_rewards)

    for index, collected_move in enumerate(collected_moves):
        collected_move[1] = normalized_rewards[index]

from torch.distributions import Categorical
import random


def get_games_data(policy_net, episodes=100,d=1):
    all_moves = [] 
    lost_count = 0
    draw_count = 0
    win_count = 0
    game_lengths_sum = 0.0
    
    for episode in range(episodes):
        
        engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("stockfish-5-linux/Linux/stockfish_14053109_x64")
        engine.configure({"Clear Hash": True})
        
        board = chess.Board(fen='rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1')
        collected_moves = []
        board_sign = 1
        move_counter = 0.0
        all = ""
        while not board.is_game_over():
            if board_sign == 1:
                # Converting the board to a tensor representation
                board_tensor = board_to_tensor(board).reshape(-1)
                board_tensor_batched = board_tensor.unsqueeze(0)
                # Getting the logits output
                logits = policy_net(board_tensor_batched)
                # Now we need to select only legal moves
                # in python-chess format
                current_legal_moves = filter_legal_moves(list(board.legal_moves))
                legal_moves_index_tensors = legal_moves_to_index_tensors(current_legal_moves)
                legal_moves_logits = logits[:, legal_moves_index_tensors]
                # Here we sample the action using valid logits
                categorical_sampler = Categorical(logits=(legal_moves_logits))
                sampled_action = categorical_sampler.sample()
                sampled_action_move_object = current_legal_moves[sampled_action]
                log_prob = categorical_sampler.log_prob(sampled_action)
                board.push(sampled_action_move_object)
                #print(str(sampled_action_move_object),end = " ")
                all += str(sampled_action_move_object)
                # Board tensor, legal_moves_indexes, sampled_action_label, reward (0 if not known yet)
                collected_moves.append([log_prob, 0.0])
            else:
                result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=d, nodes=3))
                board.push(result.move)
                all+=" "
                all+= str(result.move)
                all+=" "
                #print(str(result.move),end=" ")

            board_sign = board_sign * -1
            move_counter = move_counter + 1

        #print(f"\n--------------{board.result()}---------------\n")
        with open("Games.txt","a") as file:
          file.write(all)
          file.write(str(board.result()))
          file.write("\n\n\n")
        if board.is_checkmate():
          if board_sign == 1:
            reward = -1.0
            lost_count = lost_count + 1
          else:
            reward = 1.0
            win_count = win_count + 1
        if not board.is_checkmate():
          reward = 0.1
          draw_count = draw_count + 1
        game_lengths_sum = game_lengths_sum + move_counter    
        collected_moves[-1][1] = reward       
        discount_rewards(collected_moves)
        all_moves.extend(collected_moves)    
        engine.quit()
    
    average_game_length = game_lengths_sum / episodes
    stats = { "lost": lost_count,
              "draw": draw_count,
              "win": win_count,
            }
    normalize_rewards(all_moves)
    return all_moves, stats, win_count

import torch.optim as optim

net = Network(number_of_actions=64*64)
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

checkpoint = torch.load("/content/drive/My Drive/Checkpoint2Layer.pt")
net.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])

from livelossplot import PlotLosses
liveloss = PlotLosses()
# Stop it when you are happy with the displayed results
# Each iteration takes a while, be patient
dep=1
while dep<11:
  try:
    collected_moves, stats, wins = get_games_data(policy_net=net, episodes=100,d=dep)
    if int(wins)>70:
      dep+=1
    logs = [collected_move[0] for collected_move in collected_moves]
    rewards = [collected_move[1] for collected_move in collected_moves]
    logs_tensor = torch.cat(logs)
    rewards_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(rewards)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    policy_loss = -logs_tensor * rewards_tensor
    policy_loss = policy_loss.sum()
    policy_loss.backward()    
    optimizer.step()  
    liveloss.update(stats)
    liveloss.draw()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
torch.save({
            'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            }, "Checkpoint.pt")

#torch.save(net.state_dict(),"ChessNet.pt")
```

Comment: It would be best if you also include the link you found the code.

Comment: @AerysS I have provided the link.